# EF Core Get entities and children from a list and return paginated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm sorry I couldn't find a better/more accurate title for this question.

I'm requested to to return from the DB a PaginatedList of Person with only one of their ContactInfo. And this selection comes from a List being supplied.
So I have the following entity schema:

```
Person
  L Id
  L ContactInfos
        - { Id, Phone }
        - { .... }
```

Then I'm supplied with the following object

```
request
   L Items
       - { PersonId, ContactId }
       - { .... }
   L Page
   L PageSize
```

The People entity could have more than one ContactInfo, but If ContactId is not null (if not return all of them) I must only return the one specified.
And that for every entry in Items.

I've tried to adapt the following query, but if I must be honest I can't find a way to do it in a row so I can get a paginated result.

```cs
var query = _context.Person
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(c => c.ContactInfos.Find(x => item.ContactId == null || x.Id == item.ContactId))
    .Where(c => c.Id == item.PersonId)
    .ProjectTo<PeopleDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
}

return await query.PaginatedListAsync(request.Page, request.PageSize, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

It seems that using .Find in an .Include is not allowed in EFC, and I've tried looping the query for every item, but that doesn't give me a paginated list.
It seems that I'm pretty lost there. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I've tried the following, without success. Still trying to find a solution.

```cs
//Converting the list of objects to a single array.
var filter = new List<string>()
{
    "387552|328199",
    "387685|328199"
};

var query = from c _context.ContactInfos
    join p in _context.Person on c.Id equals p.PersonId
    where filter.Contains(c.PersonId + "|" + c.ContactId)

var totalCount = await query.CountAsync(cancellationToken);
```

But EF gives a NullReferenceException on this last line without any other info.

Also tried with

```cs
// request = {
// Items: {
//   PersonId = 387552
//   ContactId = 328199,
//  },
// ...
// }
...
where request.Items.Any(x => x.PersonId == c.PersonId && x.ContactId == c.Id)
```

But didn't work either.

Comment: I've never tried but I believe that you use `Where` within an `Include` call now. Try that rather than `Find`.

Comment: EF has no `ProjectTo` method. That's an AutoMapper method that actually adds a `Select` constructed dynamically. For filtering of relations, you can use [filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include), there's no need for `Find`

Comment: Yes, you're right. The tricky part is also that I was told to use Linq Methods syntax with AutoMapper instead of a Linq expression.

Answer (score 0):

It will be needed [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) and it's `PredicateBuilder` for building `ContactInfo` predicate. Projecting to DTO better to do without Automapper.

```cs
// assuming that request items is defined in request.Items

// collecting PersonIds
var personIds = request.Items.Select(item => item.PersonId)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

// bulding predicate
var contactInfosPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<ContactInfo>();

foreach (var item in request.Items)
{
    if (item.ContactId != null)
        contactInfosPredicate = contactInfosPredicate.Or(c => c.Id == item.ContactId && c.PersonId == item.PersonId);
    else
        contactInfosPredicate = contactInfosPredicate.Or(c => c.PersonId == item.PersonId);
}

var contactInfos = _context.ContactInfos.Where(contactInfosPredicate);

var query = _context.Person
    .Where(p => personIds.Contains(p.Id))
    .Select(p => new PeopleDto
    {
        Id = p.Id
        // other properties
        ContactInfos = contactInfos.Where(ci => ci.PersonId == p.Id).Select(ci => new ContactInfoDto
        {
            Id = ci.Id,
            // other properties
        })
    });

return await query.PaginatedListAsync(request.Page, request.PageSize, cancellationToken).;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that doesn't solve being feed with a List of items to search. It's my fault as in my question I pasted a sample code fragment from my foreach try. How would you make it if you had an array (List) of item?

Comment: I do not understand question. Update original question with additional details.

Comment: Just look at the second code snippet in that question. `request -> Items -> item1, item2...` the request is a list of persons+contactInfo. That's the part I don't know how to materialize into a single query. Being contactInfo a child object.

Comment: Ah I see. Things are worse. It is needed to build expression tree dynamically.

Comment: It is OK for you to do not use Automapper in this query?

Comment: Yes, I just realized that I should drop Automapper in this case.